# "Undefined reference to vtable in Line "in constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtable

I'm getting the error message stated in the title. I'm trying to construct a class Line which has inherited the class Shape. I get an error in the

```
Shape(color) {}
```

execution in the line constructor.

Header files (Shape and Line in one, Color in another)

Shape.h :

```
#ifndef SHAPE
#define SHAPE

#include "Image.h"
class Shape{
private:
    Color color;
public:
    Shape (const Color & col) : color(col){}
    virtual void Draw(Image & figure) const = 0;

};

class Line : public Shape{
public:
    Line (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, const Color & color);
    virtual void Draw(Image & figure) const;

private:
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
};
#endif // SHAPE
```

Image.h :

```
struct Color {
    Color( unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b ) 
    : red( r ), green( g ),     blue( b ) {
    }
    Color() : red( 0 ), green( 0 ), blue( 0 ) {
    }
    unsigned char red, green, blue;
};
```

And here is the Shape.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"

Line::Line( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, const Color &color )
    : x1( x1 )
    , x2( x2 )
    , y1( y1 )
    , y2( y2 )
    , Shape(color){
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a Color(Color&) constructor to struct Color?

Comment: That didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

struct `Color` must be declared prior to being used as a member of `Shape`.

Comment: How would one do such a thing?

Comment: By putting `Color` [above Shape](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cda018b999e446bb39a1f208ca095ba4-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: But Color is in "Image.h". And "Image.h" is included in "Shape.h". Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: It is the title : "undefined reference to `vtable for Line'"
in
, Shape (color) {

Comment: Looks like Shape.cpp doesn't get compiled/linked with the rest of the code. Check your build log.

Comment: Still hoping for an answer to this one! Been stuck for 2 days :)

Comment: Can you post you build log with command lines used to build and link?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that retracting "void" from the Draw declaration in the Line class worked. For some reason